# Copy & paste suddenly stops working

Tags: windows-7, windows, characters

When typing, my `copy` and `paste` functions suddenly don't work. This is happening most often in Google Chrome (I'm running Windows 7). I thought maybe this was due to my computer installing keyboard & mouse drivers, as it happened when it installed my display drivers, but this doesn't seem likely.

Characters  are not showing, nor does the cursor move, so the action is not working in Chrome. In order to start typing again, I have to press down the Windows key for a couple of seconds. Then I can type again without major problems. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try a different keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have something wrong with the keyboard/mouse. I suggest doing the following:
1. Install drivers for your keyboard OR mouse (the drivers you have may be corrupt)
2. Check if `CTRL` works (remember `CTRL + V` is paste and `CTRL + C` is copy)
3. If you have any other computers, see if the mouse `RIGHT CLICK` is working when you connect it to any other computer (RUNNING WINDOWS)
4. If the problem continues see if it stops when running a virtual machine

Please, try to use grammar and punctuation in the answer. I will leave a request for an edit

See a bigger list of shortcuts here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126449